How to Set Up Next.js as the Default Page Instead of WordPress Content on an Apache Server?
I have a server setup with Apache on Ubuntu, where I'm running both a Next.js application and a WordPress site. The WordPress installation is located in /var/www/html/wordpress, and the Next.js application is in /var/www/html/personal. My goal is to configure the server so that the Next.js application serves as the default page, while keeping WordPress accessible as well.
I have successfully deployed the Next.js application using PM2, and it is running without any issues or errors.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Apache Configuration:
I have modified the Apache configuration files to point to the Next.js application as the default site. My configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf) looks like this:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/personal

    <Directory /var/www/html/personal>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


.htaccess Configuration:
In the WordPress .htaccess file (/var/www/html/wordpress/.htaccess), I added the following rules to exclude the Next.js application from being processed by WordPress:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Do not process requests for Next.js app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/personal/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-admin/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress


Permissions:
I ensured that the Next.js folder and files have the correct permissions:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/personal
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/personal


Service Status:
The Next.js application is running and accessible at http://localhost:3000, but it does not seem to replace the WordPress content on the main domain (example.com).


Questions:

Are there any additional Apache configuration settings needed to ensure that Next.js serves as the default page?
Is there something missing in the .htaccess file that might be causing the issue?
How can I verify that the Apache proxy settings are correctly routing requests to the Next.js application?


What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

@DavidDE Ubuntu 24.04 lts
